# In Maven 2, how do I know from which dependency comes a transitive dependency?

Tags: java, maven-2, build-process

I would like to know which dependency described in my pom.xml brings a transitive dependency in my target directory.

To be more precise, I have the library "poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar" in my WEB-INF/lib directory and I would like to know which dependency in my pom.xml brings that.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

To add to @David Crow, here's [a dependency:tree example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html) from the Maven site:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=velocity:velocity
```

might output

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- velocity:velocity:jar:1.4:compile
```

Comment: This didn't work for me; all I got was errors about unsupported 'legacy' values. Running @David Crow's version (i.e. without the velocity flag) worked fine though.

Answer (score 58):

Using the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Answer (score 8):

If you use eclipse and the [m2eclipse plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) then there is a graphical version of dependency tree where you can filter by scope etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you run maven with "-X" switch, it will print out plenty of diagnostics. I guess the relevant dependency path can be picked up from there.

Edit: Fixed switch to uppercase.

Comment: In fact, this answer is useful. I was facing the well known [aether class undefined bug caused by upgrading my Maven from 3.0 to 3.3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/AetherClassNotFound) and the following command revealed that another maven plugin was still sourcing version 3.0.5 of org.apache.maven:maven-core:


`mvn -X dependency:tree -Dverbose |grep -C20 sonatype.aether`

Comment: While "-X" (uppercase, alternate name "--debug") is often useful, it does not tell you the origin of a version number. Not on Maven 3.6.0 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can have many reports by

> mvn site

One of them is the dependency report.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency information is also included in the Project Information/Dependencies report if you have maven generate a site for the project, using mvn site.