# How to get jar file parent dependency?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2

i have a jar file in my lib folder which is not in the pom file, so  i was wondering which dependency downloaded this jar so i can exclude this jar from the dependency.
please advise if there's a maven command to know which of my dependencies are downloading this jar.

Case:

i found in my classpath the jar slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar, and i want to know which dependency is downloading this jar so i can exclude this jar from the dependency.

Comment: Can't you see what the jar contains and google it to know which lbiraries uses this jar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Maven 2, how do I know from which dependency comes a transitive dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144/in-maven-2-how-do-i-know-from-which-dependency-comes-a-transitive-dependency)

Comment: If your dependencies are in `lib/` folder, that is certainly not maven who has put them there. Ask your team member who have committed this jar to source repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html)

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=velocity:velocity
```

you can just run

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

to see *complete* dependency tree. But good if you read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Jar file does not necessarily contain its dependencies. It can contain the list of first level dependencies in ClassPath property of manifest.mf that can be found under META-INF.
So to find dependencies you should refer to manual (if the developer wrote it) or try to resolve them using tool like JDepend.